# search string inside a word in java

Tags: java, search, string

I want to search a word inside a string :
For example  let the String be `"ThisIsFile.java"`
and let i want to search `"File.java"` or `"IsFile"`

This is something like sql `'like'` query  but unfortunately i am not 
getting that string from database.

Please suggest me any good solution for this.
Thanks

Comment: Which database vendor?  You have to use the tools they give you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a variety of ways of achieving this and the method you choose will depend on the complexity of your queries.  For a simple plain symbol/word match the String class provides a contains method that takes a single parameter, the String to search for - and returns true if it occurs within the search String.

```
bool containsFile = myString.contains("file");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
if (haystack.contains(needle))
```

? Note that this won't respect word boundaries or anything like that - it just finds if one string (`needle`) is a substring in another (`haystack`).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `String.contains()`.  Also, [check out the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) for more information about the method

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
String.contains("some string");
```